# Rails statistics gem not joining filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the rails gem 'statistics' and have added this gem in other projects and have not had this problem.  I am currently using a line like this to add filters:

```
define_statistic :sum_charged, :sum => :all, :column_name => "timelogs.charged_amount", :conditions => "subscription_opt_in = true"
```

Or even using the `filter_all_stats_on(:created_after, "timelogs.created_at > ?")` to add additional filters on the statistics...

However whenever I call `puts Timelog.get_stat(:sum_charged, :created_after => 1.year.ago)` for example, the SUM() query gets run on the database, but without any WHERE statements...

```
SELECT SUM(timelogs.charged_amount) AS sum_id FROM `timelogs`
```

What am I missing in order to add the filters to the query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was an issue of using the gem in rails 4.1.x -- I reverted the app back to 4.0.9 and it works great.  There is an issue with the base.send() function that gets sent without the filter parameters.